# In Reactivemongo Aggregation Framework, how to specify multiple keys in the group function "Max"?

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

This is sample data (expireDate is optional):

```
{"userId":"1","appId":"1","createdDate":10}
{"userId":"1","appId":"1","createdDate":5,"expireDate":30}
{"userId":"1","appId":"1","createdDate":12,"expireDate":20}
{"userId":"1","appId":"1","createdDate":12,"expireDate":5}
```

This is the aggregation function that I want to translate to reactivemongo aggregation framework:

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
{
    $match : {"userId" : "1"} 
},
{
    $group : {
        "_id" : "$appId",
        "docs" : { 
            $max : { 
                "createdDate" : "$createdDate",
                "expireDate" : "$expireDate"
            }
        } 
    }
}
])
```

To run the aggregation function on the sample data (with mongo shell 3.2.9), the result is:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "docs" : { "createdDate" : 12, "expireDate" : 20 } }
```

When I try to convert this aggregation function to reactivemongo, I realize that the group function "Max" only takes one string as parameter, so I don't know how to put both "createdDate" and "expireDate" in it. Here is what I figure out so far:

```
col.aggregate(
  Match(BSONDocument("userId" -> "1")),
  List(Group(BSONString("$appId"))( "docs" -> Max("createdDate")))
)
```

Can anybody tell me how to add "expireDate" into "Max" function?
Note that I'm using ***reactivemongo 0.11***, and upgrading to 0.12 is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reactivemongo.api.commands.AggregationFramework.GroupFunction.apply` to create a custom call to a group function. [Here is the doc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.api.commands.AggregationFramework$GroupFunction$) and [here is the source where I found it](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.11.x/driver/src/main/scala/api/commands/AggregationFramework.scala#L191).

```scala
GroupFunction("$max", BSONDocument("createdDate" -> "$createdDate", "expireDate" -> "$expireDate"))
```

Use this function instead of `Max`, so your code becomes:

```scala
col.aggregate(
  Match(BSONDocument("userId" -> "1")),
  List(Group(BSONString("$appId"))( "docs" -> GroupFunction("$max", BSONDocument("createdDate" -> "$createdDate", "expireDate" -> "$expireDate"))))
)
```

Don't forget to import `col.BatchCommands.AggregationFramework.GroupFunction`.

Of course you can define a more generic function which takes any `BSONDocument` as a parameter, if you want:

```scala
def BetterMax(doc: BSONDocument) = GroupFunction("$max", doc)
```